# Command execution failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1

Tags: java, maven

4.0.0
       org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.4
 

co.id.mii
serverside-sibkm
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
serverside-sibkm
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>1.8</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

         org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


mysql
mysql-connector-java
8.0.29

          org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-devtools
runtime
true

          org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-test
test




                org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-maven-plugin

Comment: How are you trying to run the service? Is the mvn clean install successful?

Comment: I can't run the project because of this issues, and i already install apache-maven-3.8.6

Comment: please add more detail, this can be related more than one scenario.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.